# $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q\ge 0 \mbox{ and } q^2<2\}$ is perfect?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Is the $S:=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q\ge 0 \mbox{ and } q^2<2\}$ is perfect in $\{\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|\}$?

I think it is, because $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so, given $q\in \mathbb{S}$, for every $\epsilon>0$, open ball $B_\epsilon(q)\cap S\neq {q}$ (i.e. $B$ contains more than one point, so $q$ is not isolated). Moreover, $S$ is relatively closed in $\mathbb{Q}$, since $[0,\sqrt{2}]\cap \mathbb{Q}=S$.

Please let me know if the above is correct. Just want to make sure.

Comment: $S$ is not dense in $\Bbb R$.  Do you mean to say that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Presumably you mean $S$ is dense in $[0,\sqrt{2}]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly deduced that $S$ is relatively closed in $\Bbb Q$.  To deduce that the set is perfect, it suffices to note that $S$ has no isolated points.

To that effect, it suffices to note that for every element $q \in S$ and for a sufficiently large integer $n \geq 1$, $q + 1/n \in S$.

Comment: I think this is similar to my open ball argument.

Comment: Surely you should have "for every $q$ there exists $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $q+1/n \in S$". If there is just one such integer then the point could still be isolated.

Comment: @Ian noticed the error as you commented, well spotted.

Comment: @sequence it's hard to tell what you're trying to say with your "open ball argument".  As it's currently written, it's nonsense.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What I'm trying to show with the open ball is that because $S$ is dense in $[0, \sqrt(2)]$, the open ball will necessarily contain more points than $q$. But yes, you're right, I didn't quite say precisely that. I'll have to edit now.

Comment: @sequence I don't really buy the argument "$S$ is dense in $[0,\sqrt{2}]$, therefore a ball around any $q \in S$ will contain some other point of $S$".  At the very least, there is no quick argument I see as to why the first statement implies the second.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But isn't it by definition of density of a subset of some metric space $(X,d)$ that if $S$ is dense in $X$ then for every $x\in S$ and every $\epsilon>0$,  there exists $y\in X$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$?

Comment: @sequence In fact you have that backwards: for every $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $s \in Y$ such that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$.  In any case, we can establish that $B_{\epsilon}(q) \cap S \neq \emptyset$, but further justification is required to show that $B_{\epsilon}(q) \cap S \neq \{q\}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But isn't it true that if $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $x\in X$, there exists $y\in S$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $x\in S$ there exists $y\in X$ such that  $d(x,y)<\epsilon$? I thought these statements appeared to be equivalent.

Also, a ball $B$ around $q$ intersected with $S$ must have either be $\{q\}$ (since $q\in S$) or it may include other points. But by definition of set density, it should be the case that such an intersection $\neq \{q\}$. Please point out why exactly I'm wrong.

Comment: The statements are **not** equivalent.  Take $S = \{1\}$ and $X = \Bbb R$.  It is true that for every $y \in S$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$.  It is **not** the case that $S$ is dense in $X$, which is to say that it is **not** true that for every $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $y \in S$ such that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$.

Comment: I agree that we can, in some fashion, use the definition of density to conclude that the intersection I mentioned contains more than just $q$.  However, it is not obvious how one should get from density to the desired conclusion, and so it does not suffice to say "by the definition of set density".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you please clarify how exactly the argument with $q+\frac1n$ works? Does this imply that there exists some natural number $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies that $q+\frac1n \in S$, so that however big $n$ we take, $q+\frac1n$ will be an interval intersected with $S$?

Comment: What precisely do you mean when you say "$q + \frac 1n$ will be an interval intersected with $S$"?